# filezilla error Pageant failed to answer challenge

Tags: sftp, filezilla

Anyone tell me why I getting this error, when I trying to connect my sftp through filezilla.

```
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    keyfile "/home/supravat/.ssh/pub_key"
Command:    open "54969b2f4382ecdffa0000f5@developer-ecommarce.rhcloud.com" 22
*Error: Pageant failed to answer challenge*
*Error: Could not connect to server*
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 14):

This happened to me. What I did to fix it was:

```
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

to find out what the path is. This will return something like `/home/user/.cache/keyring-XXXXXX/ssh` or `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`. Then just rename the file:

```
mv "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" "$SSH_AUTH_SOCKrem"
```

I was able to login after that.

Comment: I got this error with putty and this solved the problem as well.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me but disabled the ubuntu keyring. So I had to type my ssh password each time i used it (e.g.: each git push ..). So after i ran my sftp program (filezilla, in my case) and used it, I just did the reverse mv to restore the ubuntu keyering working.  Also note i had to do the mv on the actual file ( `mv /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh /run/user/1000/keyring/sshrem` and then later `mv  /run/user/1000/keyring/sshrem /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`)

Comment: This worked for me!!

Answer (score 1):

In my case key was in *.ppk* format so I had to install putty:

`apt-get install putty`

I have also installed putty-tools:

`apt-get install putty-tools`

And from now, everything has worked as expected in filezilla.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. 
To fix it, First I restart my device and then run

```
sudo apt-get update && upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after attempting to swap my SSH keys in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` with credentials from a PPK file using a text editor.

After switching the ssh files back to their original content and trying to connect to a saved connection via SFTP, I received the `Pageant failed to answer challenge` error.

---

This was solved by simply restarting my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix that worked in my case after doing a backup and reinstalling ubuntu and this issue occurs

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

[Source](https://prognotes.net/2019/07/filezilla-sftp-connection-error/)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error and it turns out to be a permission error.
I have given permission to my server public and private key as below.

```
chmod 400 myprivate
chmod 400 mypublic.pub
```

It is resolved for me with the above steps.