# Filezilla asks for key (which doesn't exist), only in my laptop

Tags: ftp, filezilla

When I try to connect to a FTP server with Filezilla, it asks for a password fo unlock a private key, which I never configured. The site is not configured to use keys.

If I enter my key password it works, but I'm worried, is this secure? Why is it asking my private key if I never configured it?

Other sites don't ask for this key.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean your ssh key? From another site: "The server Admin adds the public key to the SFTP server database so it is sent to your client when you login. The private key needs to be accessible by FileZilla as it is used to authenticate against the public key from the server. Filezilla at one time had some issue with being exploited (an exploited copy was posted on their site for download), but that was a while ago and I believe they have since rectified the issue. Probably more secure now than ever. Let me know if this is what you were looking for and Ill make it answer you can accept.

Comment: Yes, the ssh key. That's why I'm surprised, your text says *"The private key needs to be accessible by FileZilla as it is used to authenticate against the public key from the server"* but in this server I never configured a public key, I access with user/password.

Comment: Well, it can't be supernatural (not being rude, just trying to point out that computers either do or do not without much in between). At some point the ssh info would have had to have been configured otherwise it would have nothing to authenticate against. You could try to just put in random info and see if its not actually authenticating against anything and just letting you in regardless, but otherwise it would have had to have been given that public key at some point.

Comment: Based on your description, yes, it is secure.  The password is being used to unlock the private key for Filezilla to access it.  The password isn't being sent across the Internet.  I think what you should be concerned about is why a server which you've configured for username/password is asking to have your private key unlocked.  Maybe you should check if the site has been set to use "program defaults", etc.?  It's possible that the server is rejecting all password access and is forcing Filezilla to try a public/private key pair; Filezilla is just looking for the first acceptable method.

Comment: This [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/585164/312093) does solve my problem.